# Multiple (two) category postings on the same page.

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, slug, categories

I want two different post categories to display on one page, different divs.

I have a page called list.php which posts all the content from a category using `$this->getPostListHtml()` I added another div and replicated it but now it's just duplicating the posts from the first div into the second. How do i make a unique second div so when posts are made on the backend it only posts to the second div on the same page. Currently i'm getting category by slug and post collection and then setting order (asc) and then i'm looping through category and riders for each page that is pulling similar content. I have several pages but on each rider page it will still have to have Team 2 posts below Team. I hope that makes sense.

```
<?php if($categorySlug): ?>
    <?php $curCategory = $helper->getCategoryBySlug($categorySlug) ?>
    <?php $riders = $curCategory->getPostCollection()->addPostTypeFilter($postType->getPostType())->setOrder('menu_order','asc'); ?>
    <div class="team-header row">
        <div class="columns">
            <h1 class="team-page-title"><?php echo $this->__('Team'); ?></h1>

            <ul class="team-categories j-team-category-list">
                <?php foreach($helper->getTeamCategories() as $category): /* @var $category Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post_Category */ ?>
                    <li  class="j-team-title <?php if($category->getSlug() == $categorySlug): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></a>
                        <?php $riders = $category->getPostCollection()->addPostTypeFilter($postType->getPostType())->setOrder('menu_order','asc'); ?>
                            <div class="riders-names-list j-riders-names-list only-mobile-show">
                                <ul>
                                    <?php foreach($riders as $rider): /* @var $rider Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */ ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $rider->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($rider->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                                        </li>

                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                    </li>
                    <?php
                        if ($category->getSlug() == $categorySlug) {
                            $_theseRiders = $riders;
                        }
                    ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="riders-names-list mobile-hide">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_theseRiders as $rider): /* @var $rider Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */ ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $rider->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($rider->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="team-panel" class="team-panel">
        <div class="riders-panel" id="Rider">
            <div class="riders-list team-riders-list">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $this->getPostListHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="team-header row">

    <div class="columns">
    <h1 class="team-page-title"><?php echo $this->__('Second Team'); ?></h1>

    <div id="second-team-panel" class="second-team-panel">
        <div class="second-riders-panel" id="Second_Rider">
            <div class="riders-list team-riders-list-second">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $this->getPostListHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```